# How to rename all of my pictures back a picture format with the proper extension after accidentally renaming them

Tags: file-corruption, pictures, naming

I tried the cmd to change all my pictures but it didn't work because the naming of the pictures is difficult for the computer to rename it by the cmd trick.

This is my corrupted pictures naming:

[image: my folder pictures]

Is there a solution for this ? as naming each one would be a lot of work, because there are hundreds of pictures in the folders.

===============================================================================
Edit: adding a picture.

Here's another picture that explains how difficult it's to rename the file with simple methods; like, the cmd renaming command.

[new_picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tU5lq.png)

1. the space, tricks the command launched at cmd window to know about it, so it won't work.
2. the extension name is the biggest problem because it's different in each picture file, so it even more difficult to know the algorithm that fit this kind of naming.

I'm mean if anyone can tell what kind of algorithm I can use to follow the different file extension renaming pattern.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. Better add an example of some names, before and after the wanted change.

Comment: Don't mix "file format" and "file name". If I rename some jpeg file into "crap.xyz", it still be in jpeg format, but with obscure name. This rename also doesn't corrupt file data in any way, so it is incorrect to call this "file corruption". Also, it is very easy to determine file format with the "file" utility: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm , but I don't know how to automate it in Windows.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Thanks for correcting my understanding :) Also thanks for the link.

Comment: @harrymc I added more information.

Comment: What are you trying to rename them to? For example, to what should `personal_pics (1).009` be renamed?

Comment: Any photo format would work; let's say `.png`

Comment: Let's say `personal_pics.png` remove the space and change the extension.

Answer (score 2):

You may just select all files in the folder, then click Rename (from the right-click menu or on the top) and add a file name like `pers_pic.jpg`; this way the files will have names like `pers_pic (1).jpg`, `pers_pic (2).jpg` etc.

---

Alternatively, you may use `cmd` in the following way:

```
ren personal* personal*.jpg
```

This will add a `.jpg` extension to all files.

Source: [HTG](https://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/)

Comment: I tried that, the spaces in the names won't let me to do it with this command.

Answer (score 1):

With Total Commander (it is shareware, downloadable at https://www.ghisler.com/), you have a quite comprehensive Multi Rename Tool, where you can change the file name, extension, using regular expressions and many other items. See the screenshot of the dialog below.

[image]

Comment: Where to download it ?

Comment: https://www.ghisler.com/